# Vertices alignment in a straight line

Tags: modeling, vertices, 3d-printing

Currently working on a project where I am sculpting a statue of a dead king holding a sword.  The statue was composed of many objects which I now successfully remeshed together.

Remesh went very well except for the sword blade which totally lost its edge.
[image]
[image]

Bearing in mind that this statue is being done for 3D printing and till now the mesh is totally manifold.

**Is there a way I can align the vertice (edges) of the blade in a straight line without having to try and do it one by one?**

**Should I have marked the edges of the blade as SHARP maybe that would have helped in the remesh?**

Your answer worked thanks very much.  It's not perfect but much better than before.
[image]

Now my only problem is the sword tip which was quite thin and seems to have corroded during the remesh.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align the vertices, just scale them to *zero* along the perpendicular axis.

To scale multiple lines at once, set *Pivot* to *Individual Origins*.

[image]